# Is there a theory of identity that covers potentiality for certain traits?

Tags: identity

I know that there are many different theories of personal identity, such as the embodied mind theory, the psychological continuity theory of identity, etc.

Is there an account of personal identity that would support an identity relationship between a fetus, and its future developed self, while denying an identity to a zygote and to any other beings that lack certain traits or the potential to ever develop them?

These would seem to me to be the traits of a consistent theory of identity, however I've been unable to find one that would meet the criteria I describe. Is there a known theory of identity that does?

Comment: Asides your mentioned other contemporary philosophers hold certain preference theory of personhood identity such as Singer which starts late until forming personal preference. For your spec there's a *filial piety theory of identity* as espoused in Mahayana Buddhism's [filial piety sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/filialpiety/filialpietysutra.htm): *In the first month of pregnancy, the life of the fetus is as precarious as a dewdrop on grass...During the fourth month of pregnancy the fetus begins to assume a slightly human form...* The idea is that fetus bears the piety relation to future self...